# How to get child route path with react router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, chakra-ui

This is how I am using `useLocation` hook and `<Fade/>` for page transition effect.

```
const App = () => {
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
      <Route index element={<Welcome />}/>
      <Route path="blog" element={<Blog />}/>
      <Route path="team" element={<Team />}>
        <Route index element={<TeamList />}/>
        <Route path="sales" element={<TeamSales />}/>
        <Route path="marketing" element={<TeamMarketing />}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="about" element={<About />}/>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
}

const Layout = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return (
    <Box>
      <Nav />
      <Fade key={pathname?.split('/')[1]} in>
        <Outlet />
      </Fade>
    </Box>
  );
};

const Team = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return (
    <Box>
      <TeamCommon />
      <Fade key={pathname?.split('/')[2]} in>
        <Outlet />
      </Fade>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

The purpose of `useLocation` is just to create a new `key` for `<Fade/>` and that way re-initiate the transition effect every time the page changes.

Is there a better way to do this?

Alternatively, how to create a hook like `useChildRoutePath()` which returns current child route path?

The goal is to simplify the code like this:

```
const Layout = () => {
  const path = useChildRoutePath(); //Possible values: /, blog, team, about
  return (
    <Box>
      <Nav />
      <Fade key={path} in>
        <Outlet />
      </Fade>
    </Box>
  );
};

const Team = () => {
  const path = useChildRoutePath(); //Possible values: /, sales, marketing
  return (
    <Box>
      <TeamCommon />
      <Fade key={path} in>
        <Outlet />
      </Fade>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

(Box and [Fade](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/transitions#fade-transition) are chakra-ui components)

Comment: I guess there is no easy solution, because it's not just a simple "pop the last segment of the matched path". Actually there must be some "magic" because we make assumptions about something we cannot know, because it happens somewhere in the component tree below.

The solution must be something like: 1st: keep track of each `<Route />` that got rendered. 2nd: get the current position of the component where you call `useChildRoutePath()`. 3rd: get the path of the component one level below the current component. 4th: profit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this solution requires the use of [data api routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router) (e.g. `createBrowserRouter`) which the OP is not doing in the question. However, the usage of the data api routes are recommended moving forward, so I assume this will still be helpful to the community.

The `useMatch` ([docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match)) or `useMatches` is what I think would help solve the problem.

Both require some assumptions to be made, so I provided both in the sandbox example below. The console window will print both versions.

The gist between the two are:

- `useMatch` - You'll need to know the parent's path upfront. I haven't found a good way to pull this in dynamically without prior knowledge of the path (e.g. tossing it into a prop when setting up the router or hard coding into the component).
- `useMatches` - Has a similar issue, but it pivots to you need to know where the parent/child would be located in the router tree. It provides a list of matching paths where 0 would be the root (in this case the layout component) and the max index would be the child component you're currently on.

I haven't found a way to dynamically determine this relationship yet, but seems like it should be available somewhere in the library.

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactrouter-v6-get-child-path-from-parent-2py24p)

```
// In the Layout component
const match = useMatch("/:childPath/*") ?? "/";
console.log(match?.params.childPath)
// This will print blog, team, about, or /

// In the Team component
const match = useMatch("/team/:childPath/*") ?? "/";
console.log(match?.params.childPath)
// This will print sales, marketing, or /
```

---

For brevity, I'm not going to include a few of the files since the content for them doesn't really impact how to figure out the path. See the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactrouter-v6-get-child-path-from-parent-2py24p) if you want a complete example.

#### router.jsx

This should be roughly a conversion of what the OP routes would look like in the data api.

```
import { createBrowserRouter, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Team from "./team.jsx";
import Layout from "./layout.jsx";
import Page from "./page.jsx";

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Page page_name="Welcome" /> },
      { path: "blog", element: <Page page_name="Blog" /> },
      { path: "about", element: <Page page_name="Blog" /> },

      {
        path: "/team/",
        element: <Team />,
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Page page_name="Team Index" /> },
          { path: "sales", element: <Page page_name="Sales Team" /> },
          { path: "marketing", element: <Page page_name="Marketing Team" /> }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

#### team.jsx

```
import { Link, Outlet, useMatch } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Team() {
  const match = useMatch("/team/:childPath/*");
  const childPath = match?.params.childPath ?? "/";
  console.log(`Team Page Child Path: ${childPath}`);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>Team Nav</div>
        <Link style={{ marginRight: "20px" }} to="/team/sales">
          Sales Team
        </Link>
        <Link style={{ marginRight: "20px" }} to="/team/marketing">
          Marketing Team
        </Link>
        <div style={{ fontWeight: "bolder" }}>Child Path: {childPath}</div>
      </div>
      <hr />

      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### layout.jsx

```
import { Link, useMatch, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Layout() {
  const match = useMatch("/:childPath/*");
  const childPath = match?.params.childPath ?? "/";
  console.log(`Layout Page Child Path: ${childPath}`);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Link style={{ marginRight: "20px" }} to="/">
          Welcome
        </Link>
        <Link style={{ marginRight: "20px" }} to="/blog">
          Blog
        </Link>
        <Link style={{ marginRight: "20px" }} to="/team">
          Team
        </Link>
        <Link style={{ marginRight: "20px" }} to="/about">
          About
        </Link>
      </div>

      <div style={{ fontWeight: "bolder" }}>Child Path: {childPath}</div>
      <hr />

      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Finally, after a long time! Thanks for adding this solution.